# Documenting Fortran/C mixed code with Doxygen

Tags: c++, fortran, doxygen, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a mixed C++/Fortran codebase that I'm documenting with doxygen (1.8.8).

The C++ functions that are exposed to Fortran have a trailing underscore notation.

| FORTRAN | C++ |
| --- | --- |
| CALL SUBRA( ... ) | subra_( ... ) |

Is there a way to get doxygen to recognize and link the function call with the definition?

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.8 is quite old (August 2014) so I would at least advise to upgrade your doxygen version. For your question the mentioned `_` way is system dependent and should be replaced by a more portable way i.e. iso_c_binding  or by means of a define on the C side. In the latter case it is easy to create also a define that makes the correct connection between the Fortran and C version of your routine..